# Comparion of 2 equal strings returns false

Tags: angular, typescript, comparison

I am comparing the value of a checkbox with the values of strings in an array. I am printing out all the comparisons in like so:

```
checkSkillLevel(index: number, level: string){
console.log(this.currentAdditionalInfo.skills[index].level + "=" + level + " ?");
console.log("boolean: " + this.currentAdditionalInfo.skills[index].level == level);
}
```

In one of the comparisons, the value of the checkbox is "low" and the value in the array is also "low". I have also tried comparing them with `===`. In both cases, it returns false, as seen in my log:

[image]

What is the problem here? I have tried making the exact same comparison in an online playground where it returned `true`.

Comment: You're concatening `Boolean` *word*.. of course it won't return true for: *"Boolean:low"* and *"low"*. Use *comma* this way: `console.log("boolean: ", ...)` not +.

Comment: @developer033 Thanks. Such a stupid mistake, but I guess that's what happens when you get tired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that both string in same case.

Also please see below code

console.log("Boolean:" + "low"=="low")  --- o/p false

console.log("low"=="low") ---- o/p true